# How to vectorize a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to clean this code up and was wondering if anybody has any suggestions on how to run this in R without a loop.  I have a dataset called data with 100 variables and 200,000 observations.  What I want to do is essentially expand the dataset by multiplying each observation by a specific scalar and then combine the data together.  In the end, I need a data set with 800,000 observations (I have four categories to create) and 101 variables.  Here's a loop that I wrote that does this, but it is very inefficient and I'd like something quicker and more efficient.

```
datanew <- c()
for (i in 1:51){
  for (k in 1:6){
    for (m in 1:4){

      sub <- subset(data,data$var1==i & data$var2==k)

      sub[,4:(ncol(sub)-1)] <- filingstat0711[i,k,m]*sub[,4:(ncol(sub)-1)]

      sub$newvar <- m

      datanew <- rbind(datanew,sub)

    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know what you think and thanks for the help.

Below is some sample data with 2K observations instead of 200K

```
# SAMPLE DATA
#------------------------------------------------#
  mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100 * 20e2), ncol=20e2, nrow=100))
  var1 <- c(sapply(seq(41), function(x) sample(1:51)))[1:20e2]
  var2 <- c(sapply(seq(2 + 20e2/6), function(x) sample(1:6)))[1:20e2]
  #----------------------------------#
  mydf <- cbind(var1, var2, round(mydf[3:100]*2.5, 2))
  filingstat0711 <- array(round(rnorm(51*6*4)*1.5 + abs(rnorm(2)*10)), dim=c(51,6,4))
#------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: Please help us help you, by (1) posting some sample data, and (2) explaining what it is that you hope to accomplish here in words.  Also note you don't need to reference the data.frame you're subsetting inside `subset`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following. Notice that we replaced the first two for loops with a call to `mapply` and the third for loop with a call to lapply.
Also, we are creating two vectors that we will combine for vectorized multiplication.

```
# create a table of the i-k index combinations using `expand.grid`
ixk <- expand.grid(i=1:51, k=1:6)

    # Take a look at what expand.grid does
    head(ixk, 60)


# create two vectors for multiplying against our dataframe subset
multpVec <- c(rep(c(0, 1), times=c(4, ncol(mydf)-4-1)), 0)
invVec   <- !multpVec

    # example of how we will use the vectors
    (multpVec * filingstat0711[1, 2, 1] + invVec)


# Instead of for loops, we can use mapply. 
newdf <- 
  mapply(function(i, k) 
    
    # The function that you are `mapply`ing is:
    # rbingd'ing a list of dataframes, which were subsetted by matching var1 & var2
    # and then multiplying by a value in filingstat
    do.call(rbind, 
        # iterating over m
        lapply(1:4, function(m)
          
          # the cbind is for adding the newvar=m, at the end of the subtable
          cbind(

            # we transpose twice: first the subset to multiply our vector. 
            # Then the result, to get back our orignal form
            t( t(subset(mydf, var1==i & mydf$var2==k)) * 
              (multpVec * filingstat0711[i,k,m] + invVec)), 
          
          # this is an argument to cbind
          "newvar"=m) 
    )), 

    # the two lists you are passing as arguments are the columns of the expanded grid
    ixk$i, ixk$k, SIMPLIFY=FALSE
  )

# flatten the data frame
newdf <- do.call(rbind, newdf)
```

---

Two points to note:

1. Try not to use words like `data`, `table`, `df`, `sub` etc which are commonly used functions
   In the above code I used `mydf` in place of `data`.
2. You can use `apply(ixk, 1, fu..)` instead of the `mapply` that I used, but I think mapply makes for cleaner code in this situation